# SOAP SSL Web Service with Client Certificate java

Tags: java, exception

Before I import *.cer file to cacert of JRE it displays the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://hostname:8443/TestWS-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Service?wsdl. It failed with: 
Got sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target while opening stream from https://hostname:8443/TestWS-web-1.0-SNAPSHOT/Service?wsdl.
```

After I import *.cer file to cacert of JRE it then displays:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: HTTP transport error: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

Comment: Your SSL settings are either unconfigured or configured wrongly.  What Java library are you using to make the SOAP call?

Comment: I generate WebService in Netbeans

Comment: In SSL WebService is working properly but in client webservice it's error like above.